# Normal matrix is unitarily equivalent to a matrix with rational canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

This is a corollary from `Chapter 9` of ["Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/Jk7MtwEACAAJ?hl=en)

> If $A$ is a normal matrix with real (complex) entries then there is a real orthogonal (unitary) matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is in rational canonical form.

I can't solve this problem. It will be great if you guys can help me with this!

Comment: This statement is incorrect as stated, at least under the usual definition of rational canonical form. Please give a specific section number and theorem number so that I can look at the context of this statement.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. It is stated in "Linear Algebra" second edition by Hoffman and Kunze Section 9.6 page 356.